# "The LaTeX Companion" example environment

Tags: environments, examples

I'm a new LaTeX learner.

Is there anybody who knows "Example environment" in "The LaTeX Companion" book?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your question is quite unclear.

Comment: As Christian Hupfer says, your question is really quite unclear. What exactly is it you want to do with this "example environment"?

Comment: @moewe: I assume `\newenvironment{example}` on page 172 (German edition)?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That might be the case, so you can answer the question with "yes" `:-)`. The objective of the question still beats me, though.

Comment: @moewe: It's an assumption only, so I stay with 'The answer is **perhaps**' for the moment ;-)

Comment: @Moh Yar: At least two authors/contributors of the **Companion** are users here of TeX.SX: Frank Mittelbach and David Carlisle... they should know, but again: We don't know what you are actually asking!

Comment: This question tends to become a `The Late Companion` question if it's not updated with more information...

Comment: I suspect the question can be rephrased as: "Who knows where I can read up on how an environment works in the "LaTeX companion?"

Comment: @1010011010: Might be...

Comment: Already one close vote (not by me!) at this time, after 1 hour ;-)

Comment: [Here](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?66580-example-environment-wie-im-LaTex-Companion) is some forum where someone tries to emulate the example environments from the companion. Its in German, but maybe a copy&paste of the code fulfills you needs (?)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer 4 close votes in two hours! Yesterday happend the same with another question…

Comment: @Manuel: Yes -- do you blame me? I did not vote for close!

Comment: @Manuel: Sorry, misunderstood ;-)

Comment: Hey I was just writing an answer to this when it got closed. voting to reopen

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Another reopen vote casted!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: i was composing an answer too.  (fwiw, the op’s question seemed entirely clear, in context, to me.)

Answer (score 7):

The book is made using a makefile (unix style build script) each example is a separate document that is run as a separate latex job to produce a pdf file that is then included as an image into the main document. These example document sources are in the main document source but written out (using something equivalent to the `filecontents` environment)

The sources of the example documents use a series of conventional comments that are used in a modified verbatim environment to hide parts of the preamble, just to save space in the main book. (I don't actually have the sources to hand here so no examples:-)  If I remember correctly the first edition used a different scheme that processed all the examples in the main run, but that becomes increasingly hard to avoid artifacts from interactions between the packages, especially given the number and complexity of some of the packages in the book.

Answer (score 4):

The examples can be run as follows:

```
\documentclass{ttctexa}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{6}
\setlength\textwidth{159.0pt}

\StartShownPreambleCommands
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\StopShownPreambleCommands
\begin{document}
The right column shows the input text to be treated by
\LaTeX{} with preamble material shown in blue. In the
left column one sees the result after typesetting.
\end{document}
```

Where the class ttctexa.cls is at [tug](ftp://ftp.cstug.cz/pub/CTAN/info/examples/lgc2/ttctexa.cls)

What is missing is the script to run them all automatically from one directory (as David Carlisle described in his answer), but maybe someone has a link. However, you can run the examples without the script. Just save the class in the same directory.

Comment: The .zip file of examples for the book includes the ttctexa.cls file. (Along with ttctexamargin.cls and ttctexareport.cls). Some of the example files end with the extension .ltx and others with the extension .ltx2 . For some reason, when I run the .ltx files everything works properly, but when I try to run the .ltx2 files, I get the message `! LaTeX Error: File 'ttctexa.cls' not found.`